# How to add image from URL in ionic 3 using fabricjs

Tags: ionic-framework, fabricjs, ionic3

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

canvas.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
canvas.renderAll();
var myImg = 'http://www.logowik.com/uploads/images/511_android.jpg';


$('#addImage').on('click',addImg);

function addImg(){
    fabric.Image.fromURL(myImg, function(oImg) {
        var l = Math.random() * (500 - 0) + 0;
        var t = Math.random() * (500 - 0) + 0;                
            oImg.scale(0.2);
        oImg.set({'left':l});
                  oImg.set({'top':t});
            canvas.add(oImg);
        });
}
```

I want to add image as same as above in my ionic 3 app. New to Ionic.
The above code is for html .

Thanks in advance.

I also implement fabricjs in my app and create canvas.

Below code is for initialise the canvas

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    let w = window.screen.width;
    let h = window.screen.height;
    this.canvas.setHeight(h/3);
    this.canvas.setWidth(w/3);
    this.canvas.renderAll();
    });
this.canvas.renderAll();
}
```

Comment: what version of Ionic are you using?

Comment: I'm using  v -3.12.0

Comment: Please add your code how you added your canvas as well

Comment: ok I'll edit it

Answer (score 0):

You need something like logic below (I didn't test it)

Define your button in HTML:

```
<button ion-button (click)="addImg()">Add Image</button>
```

You've defined a fabricjs canvas, so you need just create click listener:

```
export class YourClassNameHere{
   //some properties to the class

   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
       //some constructor logic here
   }

   //button click listener
   addImg(){
    fabric.Image.fromURL(myImg, function(oImg) {
        let l = Math.random() * (500 - 0) + 0;
        let t = Math.random() * (500 - 0) + 0;                
        oImg.scale(0.2);
        oImg.set({'left':l});
        oImg.set({'top':t});
        this.canvas.add(oImg);
    });
  }
}
```